# Why does push not work when there's no collection defined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var maxNum = formData.answers = null ? Math.max.apply(Math, formData.answers.map(function (o) { return o.number; })) : 0;
var emptyAnswer = {
    "number": maxNum + 1,
    "correct": false,
    "name": "",
    "notes": "",
    "topicId": formData.topicId
};
formData.answers.push(emptyAnswer);
```

The code works if I already have an answers collection as part of formData but if formData.answers is null then it does not work. It gives a message:

```
TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'push'
    at Object.$scope.modalAddAnswer (http://127.0.0.1:81/Content/app/admin/controllers/question-controller.js:113:30)
```

Is there a way I can refactor this to make it work if there are currently no answers defined.

Comment: There is no need to quote object keys when they are valid identifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning 0 to `formData.answers` in this statement:

```
var maxNum = formData.answers = null ? Math.max.apply(Math, formData.answers.map(function (o) { return o.number; })) : 0;
```

My guess is that you are trying to compare `formData.answers` to `null`. You want to use `!=` (or `!==`) instead of the second `=`:

```
var maxNum = formData.answers != null ? Math.max.apply(Math, formData.answers.map(function (o) { return o.number; })) : 0;
```

That explains the strange message about "Object 0 has no method 'push'". Note, however, that if `formData.answers` is `null`, then your `push` still isn't going to work; you need to set `formData.answers` to an empty array. I suggest this code:

```
var maxNum = 0;
if (formData.answers == null) {
    formData.answers = [];
} else if (formData.answers.length > 0) {
    maxNum = Math.max.apply(Math,
        formData.answers.map(function (o) { return o.number; }));
}
formData.answers.push(emptyAnswer);
```

Comment: If you could reformat your answer so it shows on a few lines I think it would be more clear. How about my problem with pushing to the array if it is not there?

Comment: Now I am trying it and there is a problem. If my formdata.answers is array[0] then it seems not to work correctly

Comment: I changed to             if (formData.answers.length != 0) {
                maxNum = Math.max.apply(Math,
                   formData.answers.map(function (o) { return o.number; }));
            }  Now it works okay. Thanks

Comment: @Alan - Ah. That's because if `Math.max` is applied to an empty list, it returns `-Infinity`. You can change the `else` part to `else if (formData.answers.length > 0)`. Sorry I didn't notice that. I'll update my answer in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the key exists, and if not, create it:

```
if (!formData.hasOwnProperty("answers") || formData.answers === null) {
    formData.answers = [];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I could factor this in with the first part of the code. There I was doing a check to see if it was null. I didn't know about hasOwnProperty.

Comment: @Alan The problem seems to be that you're **setting** formData.answers to null. `formData.answers = null` means "set answer to null and return true if it was successful" whereas `formData.answers == null` means "return true if answer is null". **Edit** Just noticed that Ted Hopp said the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

initialise that variable like this:

```
 formData.answers = new Array();
```

And then remember to treat it always like an array.

Comment: Yes but what about for the case where there already is an array ?

Comment: @Alan you mean to not overwrite it?... I mean "initialise it like that". This should never be overwriting anything unless you do it after it's been filled with values.

Comment: @Alan but the code would not start with the thing already containing elements.. what I mean to say is that when you declare it.. early in the code, then do this - then any subsequent "push" will work.